# Securing Kibana with Nginx

Tags: nginx, elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

Using Nginx , With the following configuration I can make user authentication for kibana 4 version.But If I provide my username and password to user then all my information becomes accessible.

How can I make my elastic search node available for public with security?

```
server {
  listen *:80;
  server_name myserver.com;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://myserver.com:5601;
    auth_basic "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
  }
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking how to restrict access to some data in kibana to specific users or are you asking how to setup multiple users/password all that have access to the same data?

Comment: I want to share the kibana access to any user,Like if anyone can click the link and view the data's. With my configuration above I can setup the reverse proxy with nginx  and http authentication as well.But if I provide the password details to the user then that user can get full access for my elastic search.How can I overcome this?

Comment: The only way I know around this is not-free.  You need to get a support contract for ES and use the shield plugin to grant specific access to users.  That still doesn't fix the issue of them being able to see everything you have setup in kibana/changing it.

Comment: Trial option is available for shield? And Do you aware of Sinatra for kibana?